# Implementing picture zoom effect using Rmagick and FFmpeg

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, zooming, rmagick

I have a picture and I need to get zoom effect on the resulting video. I almost get the desired result.. but. The resulting picture looks a bit shaky. It's because of rounding on cropping and resizing.. so  centre of the picture shifts slightly with each conversion. What can i do with that? Or maybe there is some other method to implement it?
In the input I have 
**picture,zoom_type,zoom_percent,zoom_duration,scene_duration**
Here is part of the code which making the job:

```
img = Magick::ImageList.new(picture).first
width, height = img.columns.to_f, img.rows.to_f
img_fps = 30
if width >= height
  aspect_ratio = (width / height)
  zoom_small_size = ((height * (100 - zoom_percent)) / 100).to_f
  small_size = height
else
  aspect_ratio = (height / width)
  zoom_small_size = ((width * (100 - zoom_percent)) / 100).to_f
  small_size = width
end
factor = (((small_size - zoom_small_size) / (img_fps * zoom_duration))).to_f
while factor < 2
  img_fps -= 1
  factor = ((small_size - zoom_small_size) / (img_fps * zoom_duration))
end
total_images = img_fps * scene_duration
zoom_images = img_fps * zoom_duration_seed
new_width =  width
new_height =  height
zoom_changed_small_size = small_size

total_images.times do |i|
if zoom_images > 0 && zoom_changed_small_size > zoom_small_size
  img_n = img.crop(new_width, new_height, true)
  new_width = (width <= height) ? (new_width - factor).round : (new_width-factor*aspect_ratio).round
  new_height = (width >= height) ? (new_height-factor).round : (new_height-factor*aspect_ratio).round
  zoom_changed_small_size = (width >= height) ? img_n.rows : img_n.columns
  img_n.resize_to_fill!(width, height)
  img_n.write("#{sprintf("img_%04d.jpg" % (i+1))}")
  zoom_images -= 1
  img = img_n.copy if zoom_images == 0 || zoom_changed_small_size <= zoom_small_size
  img_n.destroy!
else
  img.write("#{sprintf("img_%04d.jpg" % (i+1))}")
  puts "Writing - #{img.filename}"
end
end
```

Then ffmpeg -y -f image2 -r 30 -i img_%04d.jpg -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4

Comment: An `affine_transform` ( http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#affine_transform )  would probably make for smoother scaling, but I don't know enough on the syntax to fully answer the question using affine transforms in Rmagick.

Comment: For a smooth transition, it is necessary to use sub-pixel interpolation. You can try to use the `resize` function, specify the filter (eg LanczosFilter) but it is not likely to solve the problem with the position of the upper-right corner of the image, which must also be specified subpixel.

Comment: It seems that `distort` can do what you want, and is easier to work with than `affine_transform`. I have updated my answer with sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest, brute-force approach you could take is to resize your starting images at the beginning of the process to be 3 or 4 times larger than they need to be at maximum zoom. That will reduce the effect of integer pixel rounding once you resize back down for the video frame, to the point where it is (hopefully) not easily visible or at least not distracting. The advantage of this approach is that you can keep most of your existing code as-is. The disadvantage is that you will need to experiment to get the right scaling factor, and depending on your source material and target video size you might end up working with some very large images.

---

If that simple patch is not to your liking, then it *is* possible to work with sub-pixel sampling zooms and pans in Image Magick . . .

I had a look at using `affine_transform`, but in practice it is fiddly. Instead, here is something using the `distort` method, which seems designed for your needs. This example takes an image, a set of points that define a "view rectangle" (which can all be floating point), and the target width, height of zoomed-in image (which should be integers):

```
def zoom_window image, from_left, from_top, from_right, from_bottom, to_width, to_height
  from_width = (from_right - from_left).to_f
  from_height = (from_bottom - from_top).to_f

  from_centre_x = 0.5 * ( from_left + from_right )
  from_centre_y = 0.5 * ( from_top + from_bottom )

  scale_x = to_width/from_width
  scale_y = to_height/from_height

  zoomed_and_scaled_image = image.distort( Magick::ScaleRotateTranslateDistortion,
    [ from_centre_x, from_centre_y, scale_x, scale_y, 0.0,
    0.5 * to_width, 0.5 * to_height]  ) { |i| i.define("distort:viewport", "#{to_width}x#{to_height}+0+0") }

  zoomed_and_scaled_image
end
```

I have tested the output of this progressively shrinking the `from_` rectangle, then using a variation of your `ffmpeg` command - it resulted in a smooth zoom effect, coping with sub-pixel accuracy nicely, even on extreme zoom-ins (although of course these look blurry). To use it, you would need to calculate the Float co-ords for the zoom window, and call the above method (or your variation of) where currently you crop and resize `img_n`.

NB I have not made much attempt to make this Ruby code "nice", it's just a proof-of-concept.

Comment: thanx! Seems like it is working solution. At least for the center zoom type. Dealing good with floats. Will dig dipper for the other zoom types.